# insert a string at specific position in a file by SED awk

Tags: shell, sed, awk, tr

I have a string which i need to insert at a specific position in a file :

The file contains multiple semicolons(;) i need to insert the string just before the last ";"

Is this possible with SED ?

Please do post the explanation with the command as I am new to shell scripting

before :

```
adad;sfs;sdfsf;fsdfs
```

string = jjjjj

after

```
adad;sfs;sdfsf jjjjj;fsdfs
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Please edit the post with a short example of your file, before and after the substitution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
echo 'adad;sfs;sdfsf;fsdfs'| sed 's/\(.*\);/\1 jjjjj;/'
adad;sfs;sdfsf jjjjj;fsdfs
```

The `\(.*\)` is greedy and swallows the whole line, the `;` makes the regexp backtrack to the last `;`. The `\(.*\)` make s a back reference `\1`. Put all together in the RHS of the `s` command means insert `jjjjj` before the last `;`.

Comment: Note, that this will insert the string before the last semicolon in **any line** containing as least one semicolon. This is not exactly insertig before the last semicolon of the _file_ as specified in the question.

Comment: @sg-lecram if the insert is for the very last `;` use: `sed ':a;$!{N;ba}; s/\(.*\);/\1 jjjjj;/' file`

Comment: @potong: I am no `sed` expert. Does this read the whole file into memory (by using the `N` command) or is this still applicable to large files? You could at least drop everything before the second last semicolon, if there is one. It's not important I am just asking out of couriosity to lern more about the power of `sed`. :-)

Comment: @sg-lecram yes it does. A more efficient solution is to use the hold space as a switch: sed '/;/{x;/;/p;x;h;$ba;d};x;/;/!{x;b};x;H;$ba;d;:a;x;s/\(.*\);/\1 jjjjj;/' file. However if the `;`'s only appear at the head of a large file the savings will be minimal.

Comment: @potong: I was expecting the savings to depend on the `;`s distribution. I like your code and I am looking forward to dive into it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/\([^;]*\)\(;[^;]*;$\)/\1jjjjj\2/' filename
```

(substitute `jjjjj` with what you need to insert).

Example:

```
$ echo 'adad;sfs;sdfsf;fsdfs;' | sed 's/\([^;]*\)\(;[^;]*;$\)/\1jjjjj\2/'
adad;sfs;sdfsfjjjjj;fsdfs;
```

Explanation:

`sed` finds the following pattern: `\([^;]*\)\(;[^;]*;$\)`. Escaped round brackets (`\(`, `\)`) form numbered groups so we can refer to them later as `\1` and `\2`.

`[^;]*` is "everything but `;`, repeated any number of times.

`$` means end of the line.

Then it changes it to `\1jjjjj\2`.

`\1` and `\2` are groups matched in first and second round brackets.

Comment: Actually, [sputnick's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10636865/1258041) is better. Simpler is better :) Works the same way, though.

Comment: I shortened said answer even further.

Answer (score 1):

For now, the shorter solution using `sed` : =)

```
sed -r 's@;([^;]+);$@; jjjjj;\1@' <<< 'adad;sfs;sdfsf;fsdfs;'
```

- -r option stands for *extented Regexp*
- @ is the delimiter, the known `/` separator can be substituted to any other character
- we match what's finishing by anything that's not a `;` with the `;` final one, `$` mean end of the line
- the last part from my explanation is captured with `()`
- finally, we substitute the matching part by adding "; jjjj" ans concatenate it with the captured part

**Edit**: POSIX version (more portable) :

```
echo 'adad;sfs;sdfsf;fsdfs;' | sed 's@;\([^;]\+\);$@; jjjjj;\1@'
```

Comment: Note that `-r` is a non-standard GNU sed option. It is better to go for a POSIX sed solution, which is easy to do in this case.

Comment: Ok, a POSIX solution was added to my POST

Comment: The poster removed the ";" at the EOL of his sample input.

Comment: You can shorten this using the `&` operator (referencing the whole match): `sed 's@;[^;]*$@; jjjjj&' <<< 'adad;sfs;sdfsf;fsdfs'`. This is also POSIX compliant since you do not need the grouping anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work for you:

```
echo "adad;sfs;sdfsf;fsdfs"| awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {$(NF-1)=$(NF-1) " jjjjj"; print}'
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
adad;sfs;sdfsf jjjjj;fsdfs
```

**Explanation:** awk starts with setting FS (field separator) and OFS (output field separator) as semi colon `;`. `NF` in awk stands for `number of fields`. `$(NF-1)` thus means last-1 field. In this awk command `{$(NF-1)=$(NF-1) " jjjjj"` I am just appending `jjjjj` to last-1 field.

Comment: @Jens check the edited answer now. Please keep in mind that I provided my answer before example added by OP. And my edit is a minor update of my original answer.

Comment: @user1271244: Explanation added, pls check.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e 's/\(;[^;]*\)$/ jjjj\1/'
```

Inserts jjjj before the part where a semicolon is followed by any number of non-semicolons (`[^;]*`) at the end of the line `$`. `\1` is called a **backreference** and contains the characters matched between `\(` and `\)`.

**UPDATE:** Since the sample input has no longer a ";" at the end.

Comment: Note that `&` is a backreference to the whole match: `sed 's/;[^;]*$/ jjjjj&/'`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'adad;sfs;sdfsf;fsdfs;' | sed -r 's/(.*);(.*);/\1 jjjj;\2;/'
```

You don't need the negation of ; because sed is by default greedy, and will pick as much characters as it can.